# If I don't know how many times something will run per second, how can I get the same output?

Tags: javascript, equation

So I have a variable `attemptedFPS`. This is how many times my loops will be run per second.

Example loop:

```js
setInterval(console.log, 1000/attemptedFPS, "Hello World");
```

So for example if the `attemptedFPS` is set to 50, that loop would run every 20 milliseconds (which would add up to 50/second).

My issue comes in having the same output no matter what the `attemptedFPS` is set to. I want to add a variable `speed` to `x` per second. (i.e. if `speed` is set to 10 that means add 10 to `x` by every second).

So, if inside that loop, I had:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  x += speed;
}, 1000/attemptedFPS);
```

Now, of course, that yields different results depending on the `attemptedFPS`.

What would be the equation for having the `speed` added to `x` per second be the same no matter what `attemptedFPS` is?

Comment: Let me clear it up so you want to know how many times was it executed because you are not sure if the thing is executing as expected right???

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer no, basically what I am asking is that after say 10 seconds of running the loop, x should be the same no matter what the attemptedFPS is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - add `speed` to `x` by every second.
> - whatever the function execute how many times (also by every second).

This could be a basic math question. Answer is quite simple:

> Divide the `speed` variable to `attemptedFPS` pieces.

Because it will get added back within your loops.

To test, this loop will run `1000/attemptedFPS` times, and whatever you set `attemptedFPS` to what, the result will always be `x += speed` (10 as the example).

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1000/attemptedFPS) {
  x += speed / attemptedFPS;
}

// result: 9.999999999999996;
```

But as you can see, it should be `10` exactly. This is because Floating point precision problem in JavaScript. I'd suggest [`Number.toPrecision())`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toPrecision) to handle this problem, however it should works.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i += 1000/attemptedFPS) {
  x += speed / attemptedFPS;
  x = +parseFloat(x.toPrecision(12));
}

// result: 10;
```

So, answer to your question:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  x += speed / attemptedFPS;
  x = +parseFloat(x.toPrecision(12));
}, 1000/attemptedFPS);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will ensure that x increases by `speed` every second, by taking into account the milliseconds elapsed since the last time the interval fired. For instance, if the interval fired 100ms ago, that would be a tenth of a second which means we add `speed * .1` to `x`.

```
let then = Date.now()
setInterval(function(){
  const timeSinceLastFrame = Date.now() - then;
  then = Date.now()
  x += speed*timeSinceLastFrame/1000;
}, 1000/attemptedFPS);
```

This is necessary because an interval is not guaranteed to execute exactly every 'frame', it only guarantees that at least `1000/attemptedFPS` milliseconds will pass before the function is enqueued in the event loop. The variance can easily exceed a millisecond which means simple arithmetic won't get you there. So instead we essentially check what time it is when the function fires to decide how much speed `x` should gain.

Comment: I like this answer and will definitely take things like this into account into my project, thanks! I would’ve accepted this but the other answer more directly answered the question, I do appreciate this feedback it is very helpful for things of this sort.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that because the actual frame rate will never precisely match your desired frame rate, X will slip over time unless you use how much time has actually passed since the last frame. Only mention it because of how you describe that requirement in your comment on the question. My solution addresses that requirement.